# I was able to do this last week but I am having an issue with running a react app project. It's stalls and it appears I have an error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I created a new folder called react and load on on vscode. In the terminal I put npx create-react-app first-app. I get this error?

> ```
> nathanvu@Nathans-MBP react % npx create-react-app first-app
> npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
> npm ERR! syscall connect
> npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
> npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, >     reason: connect ENETUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:23:443
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/nathanvu/.npm/_logs/2023-09-22T05_43_00_276Z-debug-0.log
>
> Creating a new React app in /Users/nathanvu/Desktop/react/first-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> (⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠏ idealTree:first-app: sill idealTree buildDeps
> ```

Comment: `ENETUNREACH` is network unreachable... can you access https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app using curl or a browser?